# synonym for "for lease" but free ("for lend"?)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a synonym like "for sale" but for lending.
Both, "for lease" and "for rent" sound like you have to pay, but I need a synonym for lending for free. Is "for lend" correct?

Comment: What's the context? "for sale" implies a commercial context, but commercial outfits wouldn't stay in business long if they lent things out for free.

Comment: The context is a software managing an inventory of items, where the user should be able to select, for each item, if the item is "for sale" or "for lend", meaning the user would lend the item away without expecting a payment in return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED lists the noun *lend* as "*Scottish* and *northern dialect*. Also *Australian* and *New Zealand colloquial*". I would certainly regard it as very informal. The normal noun is *loan*, so "for loan" is my recommendation.

Comment: This has the advantage of being short and matching the pattern of "for sale" -- so if I were writing software like OP's I might use it. However, note that to my American ears it sounds kind of British and formal. If I wanted to complete the sentence "the library has a lot of books ______" in the briefest way possible, I'd use "to lend", "to borrow", "for borrowing", or "for lending".  "For loan" works, but wouldn't come to my tongue quickly.

Comment: That's interesting, @joseph_morris, because when I was growing up, I thought of _loan_ as an American word. I now realise that that was the verb, which is rarely used in BrE. And the noun _loan_ is common here, but only for things that young children don't encounter much, such as bank loans. I agree with you about the library, though.

Comment: @joseph_morris How would you say "This book is for sale", but with "lend" instead?

Comment: Most likely I'd say "this book can be borrowed". "This book is for lending" works, but sounds more like that's the purpose of the book, a la "these books are made for walking". The thing is, "for sale" has become a set phrase (due to classified ads and signs probably), but no such set phrase exists for gratis lending.

Comment: So on the one hand, bummer, no set phrase. However, in the absence of such a set phrase, multiple alternatives will sound acceptable. In your case for categories in a software program I'm torn between "for loan" which would look symmetrical w/"for sale" in a drop-down menu; and "for lending" which sounds better in a sentence.

Comment: I think I will use "for loan". Thank you @joseph_morris

Answer (score -1):

'For Lend' or 'For Borrow' sounds appropriate. If it is meant to be software people can use for an array of situations, maybe some term like 'For Contract' where someone can set their own terms as well wouldn't go amiss.